# Como reproduzir um fluxo streaming mms no ASP NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, streaming

Eu uso o `Microsoft Encoder` para transmitir um vídeo via protocolo `MMS`.

O vídeo é transmitido por streaming. É a filmagem de um evento sendo transmitida sincronizadamente para a rede (por enquanto de forma local).

Não é um vídeo que está no servidor e sim uma transmissão que os clientes vão captar do ponto em que conectarem-se na página em diante.

Eu vi uns exemplos do uso do `HTML 5` no Razor para a reprodução, mas somente para vídeos do servidor não para recepção de recursos de mms da rede.

```
<video controls="controls" height="320" width="480">
        <source src="/api/videos/mp4/OMundoUmMoinho" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Esse exemplo eu vi em [ASP.NET Web API / HTML5 - Streaming de áudio e vídeo assincronamente](http://codingfirst.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/transmitindo-audio-e-video.html)

O recurso está sendo transmitido continuamente, o endereço por enquanto é `mms://localhost:8080`

Até então eu capto a transmissão usando o programa `VLC Media Player` através da função `Abrir Fluxo de Rede` no menu arquivo.

Desde então agradeço.

Comment: O exemplo é pra Web API, que em teoria é quase a mesma coisa que no ASP.NET MVC. Qual seria a dúvida?

Comment: Em vez de reproduzir um vídeo armazenado no servidr, como no exemplo; eu quero reproduzir um fluxo streaming que está sendo transmitido pelo protocolo mms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso existem diferentes caminhos a serem seguidos, um deles seria abandonar o player nativo do html5 e utilizar algum plugin como o VLC, particularmente eu não gosto dessa alternativa.

```
    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
       pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
       autoplay="yes" loop="no" 
       width="480" height="320" 
       target="/api/videos/mp4/OMundoUmMoinho" />
```

Você também pode mudar seu encoder, dependendo do seu controle sobre o ambiente de servidores, para utilizar o [ffserver](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ffserver). Dessa forma é possível alterar a forma como você entrega o conteúdo sem sair das definições do Html5.

Não tenho como testar aqui, mas talvez se você conseguir alterar o endpoint do seu stream no encoder para expor o endereço com uma extensão de arquivo, talvez funcione também.

```
/api/videos/mp4/OMundoUmMoinho/video.mp4
```

Não obstante, também é necessário estar atento a compatibilidade do tipo de conteúdo com a implementação do elemento `<Video>` em diversos browsers e os tipos de mídia suportados. ([Referência](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp))

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.